# Como modificar commits que não receberam push

Tags: git, commit

Eu preciso editar a mensagem de um commit e adicionar mais um arquivo.

Eu ainda não dei Push no commit, existe uma forma de resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim!

Você pode desfazer seu último commit **local** (sem ter dado o push), voltando ao estado anterior do commit e sem perder as alterações feitas no mesmo.

Apenas faça:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Sendo `1` o número de commits para trás que deseja desfazer. Como você quer apenas o último, você usará `1` (um).

Após isto, suas alterações pré-commit serão todas mostradas como *unstaged* no `git status` e será preciso adicionar elas novamente com `git add .`.

Agora é só adicionar o arquivo que deseja e fazer o commit novamente, alterando a mensagem do mesmo.

Comment: Tem também o `git commit --amend`, que anexa no último commit as coisas (no lugar de desfazer). Você fala ou eu falo?

Comment: Eu ia comentar sobre o `amend`, mas como ele não quer apenas alterar a mensagem do commit, acabei achando melhor não citar para não confundir. O que acha?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, olhei a documentação agora. Não sabia que o `amend` conseguia alterar o último commit inserindo mais informações. Acho justo você falar :)

Comment: Então pronto, depois de chegar no trabalho eu escrevo =]

Comment: Muito obrigado Jefferson por complementar a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Se você deseja fazer uma alteração no **último** commit, mantendo todos os os outros inalterados, você pode fazer um `git commit --amend`.

O `amend` (em português seria traduzido para "melhorar" ou "emendar" [segundo o Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amend)), a grosso modo, funciona igual ao commit normal. Você usa a [área de elenco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320129/64969) para colocar as **mudanças adicionais** e, na hora de realizar o compromisso, você diz que é um "emendo" do compromisso anterior.

Através do [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com), você pode selecionar a opção de "corrigir último commit" para realizar esse `commit --amend`:

[image: selecionando a opção de emendar o commit]

Eu normalmente uso o `--amend` para enviar alguma correção em um commit que já fiz por engano. Por exemplo, precisei declarar um método novo em uma interface e na classe que a implementa. As vezes acontece de eu elencar apenas a classe alterada e esqueço da interface. Outro exemplo, também muito comum, é quando crio um arquivo novo e o uso em um arquivo previamente existente, ou então juntar o `changelog` à mudança do código já commitada.

Note que esse emendo não necessita de arquivos na área de elenco. Ele pode ser feito para alterar a mensagem de commit apenas.

Também é possível fornecer outros parâmetros de emendo, como [o autor do commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/4438007).