# Staging Area do GIT é inútil?

Tags: git

Entendo o fluxo de trabalho quanto ao processo que leva a um commit (diretório de trabalho -> staged area -> repositório), mas ainda não consegui entender a utilidade da *Staging Area* na prática.

Meu pensamento é o seguinte, posso usar o diretório de trabalho e não preciso da *Staging*. Ao modificar um arquivo (se o mesmo estiver mapeado) o GIT registra as mudanças, posso então realizar todas as modificações necessárias ao meu commit e então envia-las ao repositório, sem ter de passar pela Staging.

Sei que outros sistemas de controle de versão trabalham deste modo, mas o GIT é diferente. A final qual a utilidade prática da *Staging Area* no GIT ?

Comment: Se fosse não existiria, né?

Comment: Correto, e aceito, mas não compreendo, gostaria de compreender :(

Comment: Os commits no Git são permanentes, daí é interessante uma área para que você pode preparar tudo com calma e atenção antes de finalmente submeter as alterações ou simplesmente mudar de ideia, dar um git reset, e voltar à estaca zero.

Comment: E porque o repositório de trabalho não pode ser usado para isso ? Posso fazer nele tudo que se pode fazer na stating area, correto ?

Comment: @AllanDantas sobre esse comentário de "se é possível fazer em Y, por que existir X?", isso que você fez foi uma falácia. Assembly é Turing completo, portanto toda e qualquer computação pode ser feita em assembly puro. Por que então existe C?, ou Java?, ou Python?, já que eles seriam apenas redundância perante o assembly que é completo? E por que assembly se posso fazer direto em linguagem de máquina que é o destino final do assembly? Assembly é muito valorizado, deveríamos todos escrever programas com [borboletas batendo asas](https://xkcd.com/378/)

Comment: O que o @JeffersonQuesado quis dizer que dá mais trabalho, o Staging é um mecanismo que protege o que ainda não é definitivo sem você precisar tendo grandes preocupações mais trabalhosas ou que podem dar errado se esquecer de alguma coisa. Você pode escolher fazer na mão e correr riscos ou pode usar o mecanismo útil.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sinceramente, acredito que a falácia é sua - o que o allan perguntou, e o exemplo que ele deu são bem simples: se uma coisa substitui todas as funcionalidades de outra, elas supostamente são intercambiáveis nesses quesitos - c, java e python incluem todas uma série de funcionalidades que não estão prontas para serem utilizadas em assembly, mesmo podendo ser reconstruídas - então a comparação não é válida; pelo visto a staging area oferece uma funcionalidade que sem ela não teríamos - que funcionalidade é essa?

Comment: Exato @Blogueira, para sua colocação: "pelo visto a staging area oferece uma funcionalidade que sem ela não teríamos - que funcionalidade é essa?", alguns estudos me mostraram que sim, isso é um fato. A Staging oferece muito mais funcionalidades, curiosamente encontrei vasto material em inglês sobre o assunto (artigos e até postagens no stack overflow em inglês). Agora já compreendo, irei responder a pergunta em breve, compilando todo meu entendimento. Enquanto isso deixo aqui um excelente artigo sobre o tema: http://gitolite.com/uses-of-index.html

Comment: Na maioria das vezes eu uso `git -commit -am "mensagem"` para não ter que ficar estagiando as alterações, se fizer assim será como se uma Staging Area não existisse. Porém as vezes eu a uso para "commitar" alterações específicas sem incluir alguns arquivos de projeto que para aquele commit é desnecessário.

Comment: @MarcioRodrigues eu particularmente não gosto muito dessa estratégia. Eu abomino meu uso pessoal de `git commit -a`, ainda mais porque eu faço muitas mudanças em muitos pontos que não quero que subam (como mudar o banco de dados onde estou testando). Eu também sou muito a favor da revisibilidade dos commits, então cada commit para mim deve ser uma história única e fácil de entender, de preferência de maneira atômica. Por curiosidade, seus projetos são em que linguagem?

Comment: Eu também abomino o meu, mas eu coloco as mensagens certinhas, rsrs. Para quem não acha necessário usar a staging (eu uso de vez em quando) esse comando já resolveria. No GIT trabalho com Delphi, scripts PostgreSQL, JSON e markdown.

Comment: Vale lembrar que outros sistemas de versionamento como, por exemplo, no SVN, não existe a Staging, neste caso há uma mudança na mentalidade de trabalho,(onde só podemos trabalhar em um único commit por vez) @JeffersonQuesado considera tão religiosa a Staging, pois realiza múltiplas alterações, neste caso ele não pode pensar diferente, agora quem costuma trabalhar  um pouquinho mais próximo da mentalidade do SVN não tem uma visão tão religiosa assim da Staged. O git possibilita os dois fluxos de trabalho (pela staged e o commit direto) cabe ao utilizador escolher o melhor modo para si.

Comment: @MarcioRodrigues no meu caso é principalmente Java e Bash. Às vezes markdown também, mas pouco em comparação às outras duas. Bem, sou extremamente cuidadoso e desconfiado nos meus próprios commits, eu acho que só faço isso com certa segurança no commit inicial de projetos

Comment: @AllanDantas no SVN, como é centralizado, ele foi pensado em um contexto diferente do commit. É tanto que o SVN é no estilo "_merge before commit_", enquanto que o git e o hg (e outros distribuídos) são mais focados em "_merge afete commit_". O comprometimento no SVN é muito mais sério do que no git. Na pior das hipóteses, se no git você destruir o histórico, é fácil reescrever antes de publicar. O jeito SVN de se fazer o commit também lembra aquela atividade de final de dia em que você seleciona o que precisa subir na pressa, já o git permite algo mais paulatino, que pode durar dias...

Comment: De fato, o GIT permite a criação de pacotes lógicos muito mais bem estruturados e pensados em comparação com o modo de trabalho do SVN, e grande parte disso vem em virtude da implantação da Staged. Mas acredito que abominar o commit direto de forma tão rigorosa seja manter-se um pouco engessado (claro que tudo depende do modo como cada um trabalha), no seu estilo de trabalho pelo que pude notar a Staged é indispensável, entretanto podem surgir certas situações onde pular a area de preparação seja a ação mais inteligente, se não por que haveria essa possibilidade no GIT, não acha ?

Comment: @AllanDantas eu acho que existem sim casos específicos. Mas ainda assim, é um belo dum desperdício de potencial

Comment: Relacionado: [Quais as diferenças entre os estados dos arquivos do Git (untracked, unmodified, modified, staged)?](/q/326086/112052)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Entenda a existência do *Staging Area* mais como um recurso do que uma obrigação de uso no Git.

É perfeitamente possível trabalhar com o Git sem nunca usar o *Staging Area*, e não há nenhum problema em abrir mão dela no seu dia-a-dia de desenvolvedor. Mas ela pode ser bem útil se souber como usá-la.

O principal uso dela é fazer com que você tenha mais **controle** de quais alterações quer commitar por vez, permitindo **commits menores** sem muito esforço extra para isto.

Imagine que você tenha feito uma porção de alterações em vários arquivos do seu projeto: script de banco de dados, arquivos de configuração, arquivos fonte, novas imagens inseridas, etc. É claro que você poderia fazer um único commit com tudo:

```
git commit -am "Funcionalidade XYZ implementada. Imagens inseridas, 
    arquivos de configuração alterados, HTML de criar, 
    editar e excluir criados. Scripts SQL inseridos para os novos parâmetros"
```

Bem, será um senhor commit com uma senhora mensagem de commit.

Talvez você gostaria de separar melhor os arquivos enviados a cada commit, deixando mais organizada as alterações feitas:

```
git add config/application.yml
git commit -m "Configurações alteradas"

git add images/imagem1.jpg images/imagem2.jpg 
git commit -m "Novas imagens"
```

E assim por diante.

Sem o *Staging Area*, você teria muito trabalho para fazer a mesma coisa: precisaria fazer um diff das alterações para salvar o que fez, deixar apenas o quer quer enviar no commit atual, salvar os arquivos binários em outro local até fazer o commit no qual elas vão, etc.

O *Staging Area* também pode ser usado em situações mais específicas, como quando você está no meio de uma implementação no código e surge algum bug que precisa ser corrigido antes. Você pode simplesmente corrigir o bug no arquivo, fazer um `git add` apenas do arquivo alterado e fazer o `git push`, sem se preocupar com as outras alterações.

Answer (score 12):

Vamos começar analisando os nomes?

- *staging area*: área para elencar
  Nessa parte, você está montando um elenco, mas ainda não o tem completo. Você ainda está chamando os "atores" que vão "participar da peça", as mudanças significativas que você quer por para a posteridade
- *commit*: o mais próximo que consigo traduzir vem de sua forma substantivada: *commitment*, ou **compromisso**
  Nessa parte, você está pronto para selar um compromisso para a eternidade. Com tudo que foi elencado, você pôs as peças importantes em jogo e está pronto para assumir um compromisso. Daí, *commit* creio que possa ser traduzido como o verbo reflexivo "comprometer-se".

Tem outros lugares também em que se usa *commits*, mesmo que sem tradução clara. E um dos principais é em banco de dados (vou chegar no ponto em que o `git` é um banco de dados de uso específico, deixa isso pendurado por um tempo). Você pode fazer todo o trabalho no banco de dados sem fazer uso de *commits*, que por sua vez é o passo final de uma **transação**? Claro que pode! Mas isso oferece riscos.

> Por sinal, tem bancos de dados que não oferecem outros meios de atualizações de dados que não for por transação e fechando em *commit*, como o [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite). Se você não fizer uso desse recurso explicitamente, ele engloba cada operação de DML que resulte em alterações de dados dentro de um `begin transaction; ... seu update/insert/delete ... ; commit` automaticamente.

Como funciona a transação no banco de dados? Basicamente nela você chama todos os atores, que são manipulações de dados e/ou estrutura, e então fecha alegremente um compromisso ou dá pra trás e volta tudo rolando (*roll back*).

Nesse sentido, a transação funciona como uma área para elencar mudanças e assumir um compromisso.

Eu citei acima que o `git` é um banco de dados de fim específico. Ele não é um banco de dados relacional ou NoSQL, ele é um banco baseado em alterações de segmentos de textos (ou binários, mas ele mesmo foi feito para textos, binário quase sempre é marcado como alteração completa). Ele simplesmente armazena o histórico de criação dos documentos e, também, os passos que eles sofreram para chegar em um outro estado.

No caso do `git`, o repositório é entendido como uma única entidade de conhecimento, mas que possa conter diversos documentos. Às vezes, uma alteração de documento requer que outro também o seja (por exemplo, extrair uma função de um arquivo fonte generalizando-a em outro arquivo fonte). Então é natural que, para a mudança ser *atômica*, ela precisa realmente ocorrer em 2 ou mais cantos *ao mesmo tempo*. Sem essa garantia, você poderia ter mudanças que tornariam inconsistentes as informações que precisam ser compartilharas em diversos documentos.

Bem, então para agrupar essas mudanças há o **compromisso** de sua parte. O seu compromisso consiste de uma série de deltas (ou alterações de documentos), sua assinatura (nome/email) e uma mensagem para indicar com o que você está se comprometendo. É, nesse momento, você se casou com o código, parabéns. Mas saiba que não há divórcio, compromisso eterno.

Se não existisse a área para elencar, você poderia selar um compromisso com um conjunto de deltas sempre que sentir a necessidade. Mas, não há divórcio... e se você estivesse apenas se preparando? Bem, nesse caso, você assumiria um compromisso  potencialmente errado. E não queremos manter erros para além da eternidade, não é mesmo?

Aqui entra a área para elencar. Você ainda não está pronto para assumir o compromisso, mas começou a elencar as coisas importantes. De funcionalidades extras, você poderia usar o *stash* para por debaixo do tapete mudanças que não estão elencadas para ver se elas são atômicas por si, ou se poderia ter feito de maneira diferente. Também tem o caso que o [@Marcel Felipe respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/320229/64969), em que, após "sujar" sua área de trabalho, você não sela um compromisso, mas dois ou mais. Eu mesmo muitas vezes faço como o Marcel falou e seleciono o conjunto de linhas necessárias para a mudança desejada, sem me preocupar em elencar o arquivo inteiro.

Então, voltando ao cerne da questão: Qual a utilidade da área para elencar? Ela é inútil mesmo?

Ela serve para que você possa assumir compromissos sem arrependimentos futuros (ou quase isso...). Ela também permite que você **monte** paulatinamente o seu compromisso, as suas mudanças. Adicionalmente, você também pode utilizá-la para validar as mudanças com as quais você quer se comprometer.

---

Sim, eu sei, tem o `git commit --amend`, mas ele parece mais um "pacto pós-nupcial", e ele não deve ser abusado demais quando o seu compromisso se tornou público, quando você empurrou para o remoto as mudanças que acha necessárias.

Answer (score 3):

Aqui está um exemplo de quando a staging area é útil pra mim:

No meu dia-a-dia de desenvolvimento no trabalho é muito comum receber uma demanda grande, que necessita de muitas alterações, então eu abro uma feature e começo o meu trabalho.

Durante o meu trabalho eu desenvolvi uma tela (html e css) porem ainda estou desenvolvendo suas funcionalidades (javascript), nesse instante alguém da equipe pede para dar uma olhada no layout da nova tela, ou seja, eu preciso commitar apenas o html e o css, é aí que a staging area é util, adicionando apenas o html e o css eu posso commitar apenas eles sem precisar remover meu código javascript. Se não existisse a staging area eu acabaria por commitar o javascript junto podendo levar vários bugs juntos.

Comment: Seu exemplo é interessante e útil, mas não completo. Pelo que falou, você pode fazer a mesma coisa só com commits direto, reforçando a tese de que a área de elenco é inútil.

Comment: @MarcelFelipe essa é sem dúvida a utilidade mais básica da staging, obrigado por compartilhar sua experiencia. Deixo aqui um artigo sobre o assunto, que trás estas e outras grandes funcionalidades da staging area: http://gitolite.com/uses-of-index.html

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Como você faria o commit do HTML e do CSS sem levar o Javascript junto e sem precisar apagar o arquivo?

Comment: @MarcelFelipe o `git commit` aceita uma lista de arquivos como argumento. Então poderia fazer algo como `git commit -m "Novas e melhores classes de estilo" $(find . -name "*.html") $(find . -name "*.css")`. Que tal? Sem elencar, _commit_ direto

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Essa não seria uma solução se eu tivesse um código dentro da tag <script>. Usando o staging interativo eu posso commitar apenas a parte html e css do meu arquivo. Veja isso: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

Comment: @MarcelFelipe sim, elencar apenas as linhas de mudanças. Isso não me ficou claro quando li a primeira encarnação da sua resposta (nem na segunda), pois entendi (e continua com margem para este entendimento) que eram arquivos de html,  css e js separados. Agora com seu comentário ficou clara a sua intenção. Como te mencionei na minha resposta, preciso corrigi-lá agora com a interpretação adequada

Comment: Mesmo assim, isso do elenco interativo não vejo como a real utilidade do commit, mas como uma de suas consequências, uma funcionalidade que advém de seu uso básico