# Como clonar um projeto direto de uma Branch?

Tags: git, versionamento, gitlab

Utilizo o Gitlab e o Visual Code para fazer versionamento de código e estou com o seguinte problema:

Ao clonar um projeto direto da `master` e depois fazer o `git pull origin tv_version` os meus arquivos ficam dando como
**"CONFLITO DE MERGE"** e caso eu clone direto do meu branch `tv_version` usando `git clone -b tv_version <local do git>`, o
Visual Code dá como **"ARQUIVOS ESTAGIADOS"**.

A ideia dos branchs:

O `master` e o `tv_version` eles contém praticamente os mesmos arquivos, a única diferente é que o `tv_version` possui alterações que o `master` **não possui e nem deve possuir**.

**Dúvidas:**

1. Por que dá o famoso conflito de merge e como resolvê-lo?
2. O que é "Arquivos Estagiados", o porque dá isto e como resolvê-lo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Recomendo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320129/99718

Comment: O que está colocando como `<local do git>` no comando?