# Diferença do: "git commit -am" e "-m"

Tags: git, terminal, commit

Qual seria a diferença entre digitar: `git commit -m "Teste"` e `git commit -am "Teste"`?

Estou aprendendo sobre Git e gostaria de saber como diferenciar isso.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O comando:

```
git commit -m "Teste"
```

Faz o commit apenas dos arquivos modificados e que encontram-se adicionados na área de *stage* (`Changes to be committed`) do Git. Ou seja, trata-se apenas dos arquivos que você adicionou usando um comando como este:

```
git add nome_arquivo.txt
```

Ou este:

```
git add .
```

Já o comando:

```
git commit -am "Teste"
```

Faz duas coisas: adiciona **todos** os arquivos modificados na área de *stage* e, em seguida, faz o commit dos mesmos. Em termos de comando, é o mesmo que você fizesse estes dois comandos abaixo:

```
git add .               # adiciona todos os arquivos modificados no stage
git commit -m "Teste"   # faz o commit dos arquivos modificados
```

Comment: De modo geral, sobre a [`staging area`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320129/64969)

Comment: Então não preciso usar o `git add ...` e posso usar só o `-am`? Isso vai facilitar meu processo.

Comment: @Henrique Depende. Se tiver algum arquivo que vc não quer que vá no próximo commit, é melhor fazer `add [arquivos que quero]` e `commit` (sem o `-a`) separadamente. Mas se quer tudo seja *commitado*, use `-a`

Comment: Sim, sim, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Ao invés de você precisar fazer um `git add <meu arquivo>` (que adiciona o arquivo para realizar o seu commit) e depois fazer um `git commit -m <minha mensagem de commit>` (que commita sua alteração atribuindo uma mensagem a ela), o `git commit -am <minha mensagem de commit>` já faz esses dois passos de uma só vez.

Answer (score 4):

O `git commit -m` define apenas o commit das modificações que estão previamente adicionadas na sua árvore, combinando isso a opção `-m`, que espera uma mensagem para dar vida ao seu commit.

Utilizando o `-a` você além do commit e mensagem, adiciona todos os arquivos que **ja são trackeados pelo git**, cuidado, pois a opção -a não adiciona arquivos criados no momento, apenas aqueles que form modificados ou deletados. Assim, você pode unir o `-a` com o `-m` resultando em `-am` poupando o tempo de realizar o `git add <diretório(s) ou arquivo(s)>`